# Should I do a second master to increase my chance of getting into a PhD program?

Tags: phd, supervision, second-degree

In my country (France), your first and second year of your Master are two different program. My second year of Master was in a remote program (the exams were not remote).

After 20ish applications, I have only got shortlisted for two of them.

Recently, a university's prof had the kindness to review my application material and told me that my CV and motivation letter are good and that the only issue he sees is my Master being a remote one and the fact that I had not applied to french universities but European ones (because of deadline issues related to the end date of my Master).

He advised me to do a second Master.

Do you think it is worth a try or will it be a waste of time ? I will have to wait until next September to start the new Master...

I thought of doing more research to compensate but in France, at least in Physics, researcher only take in students for their thesis and not people who are not students anymore.